# googlemap-route on two computers synchroned and updated over GPS

Tags: google-maps, gps

I want to have a software to manage my drivers of a delivery-service.

My plan:

- A googlemaps-route planner where i can fit in the orders to drive.
- The driver has a netbook with the same googlemaps-route planner in his car. it gets synchroned with my map.
- the driver has a GPS that show me his position on the map.
- the driver can use the route-planner as a navigation software.

Is this possible? how can I implement it?

Is there already a solution where I can use?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy solution for that. This will require some advanced programming skills, so if I were in your place I would simply equip your driver in a tablet/smartphone which usually come with GPS receiver and try to find ready made solution for Android/iOS platform as those are the most popular today.

Comment: I know, that it isn`t easy.
But it s also not easy to find a good ready made solution to guide his drivers.
The solutions I know are not really good or just very very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Answers to your 4.points:

1) can work, you send the position via internet to the app on his tablet which calls the routeplaner for that position.

2) yes, see 1)

3) yes, your app on the netbook sends the coodsinates to your server.

4) no, what i know this is prohibitted by google. see google license conditions, and further it would technically not work.

Point 4 could theoretically be solved by OpenSoure Navi solution(s) but they all give a bad route compared to professional navis.

recently TomTom provides a solution to interact with a (special version) of a TomTom navi.

But consider that your task needs some person years of effort.

Comment: thx for this great feedback.

Ok, I see can only do it, like i already have tested it.

The navigation-use is the point.
I wanted to use the googlenavi, because i can change manualy the waypoints for the driver.
Because every Navigation-Software I know uses bad ways in City.
(Prever bigger roads, dont know traffic light settings,...)
It s only a few meters or minutes each time, but you can save a lot time/money if you know the city like me :)

thx so far. I try on now to realize it as far as it s possible.

Comment: "because i can change manualy the waypoints for the driver" Can you change the waypoint programmatically, such that google navi  navigates the waypopints you provided programmatically?

Comment: I dont know, if it s possible to set waypoints programmatically.
But i can send the manually changed route by link. So I think, there will be a way.